# Strange behavior in Nebula CDateTime

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, nebula

I am trying to CDateTime as a cell editor for my swt table control. When I run a standalone CDateTime sample (from [here](http://git.eclipse.org/c/nebula/org.eclipse.nebula.git/tree/widgets/cdatetime/org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.cdatetime.snippets/src/org/eclipse/nebula/widgets/cdatetime/snippets/CDTSnippet02.java)), this is what it looks like:

[image: Regular CDT behavior]

The CDateTime is created like this:

```
final CDateTime cdt = new CDateTime(shell, CDT.DROP_DOWN | CDT.DATE_SHORT | CDT.COMPACT);
cdt.setSelection(new Date());
```

Notice the icon that is causing the drop down - it looks like a calendar. You can see the month/year, and there are 2 arrow buttons and a "today" button in the left corner of the header. The date is also written into the textbox correctly when you select a date.

However, when I try to add it as a cell editor, this is what it looks like:

[image: CDateTime as a cell editor]

Notice that the icon is different and the header parts are different. Also notice how I selected a date and get this weird number - with a month of 32! - in the text box. When the popup goes away, the date is correct, but this strange behavior looks odd and is worrying.

I created the CDateTime like this:

```
    final int style = getStyle() | CDT.DATE_SHORT | CDT.DROP_DOWN | CDT.COMPACT ;
    this.dateTime = new CDateTime(parent, style);
    this.dateTime.setPattern("mm/dd/yyyy");
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

i know this is an old question, but here is the answer: the pattern you set is wrong, "mm" represents minutes. instead you can use "MM" to get the month:

```
    dateTime.setPattern("MM/dd/yyyy");
```